# Charset fix to UTF8 - encoding/decoding values using JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, cookies

I have a problem with values in cookies. I am creating cookies using this code:

```
// var
$firstName = $_POST['name'];
$lastName = $_POST['sname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['tel'];

setcookie("firstName", $firstName);
setcookie("lastName", $lastName);
setcookie("email", $email);
setcookie("phone", $phone);
```

And filling form using this:

```
var fillForm = function() {

    firstName = getCookie('firstName');
    lastName = getCookie('lastName');
    email = getCookie('email');
    phone = getCookie('phone');

    $('#name-input').val(firstName);
    $('#name2-input').val(lastName);
    $('#email-input').val(email);
    $('#phone-input').val(phone);
}
```

And my problem is that, when the user writes the name `Łukasz` or normal email `some.email@domain.com`, cookie values are in this format: name `%C5%81ukasz` and email `some.email%40domain.com`.

I tried to use decoding and encoding functions from Stack Overflow but the best result I receive from the input `%C5%81` is the letter `Å`(ASCII) but I need to get `Ł` (UTF8).

Comment: How you decode value?

Comment: decodeURIComponent('%C5%81ukasz') || decodeURI('%C5%81ukasz') works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `unescape()` function caused the problem. Switching to `decodeURI()` or `decodeURIComponent()` fixed it. Thank you very much! :))